# Inline a type definition in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inline, type-definition

I'm writing a type definition file (`index.d.ts`) for a jQuery library that doesn't come with a type definition.
The methods of that library repeatedly accept parameters of the same multi-type (`string | number | []`) so I defined it as a `CustomType`:

```ts
export type CustomType = string | number | [];

declare global {
    interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
        setFoo(foo: CustomType): this;
        setBar(bar: CustomType): this;
    }
}
```

When I now want to call `setFoo()` on a jQuery object, the type hinting (of IntelliJ) shows that a parameter `foo: CustomType` is expected which doesn't help fellow devs without looking up what that type resembles.
Instead I'd love to see the type hinting to show `foo: string | number | []`.

For example, in C++ there is this concept of an `inline` function which basically tells the compiler to put the code of the inlined functions body right into the block where it's called rather than to call / jump to the function. Is there something similar in TypeScript?

**How can I force TypeScript to inline this `CustomType` and make it show as `foo: string | number | []` instead of `foo: CustomType`?**

### Ugly Solution

```ts
declare global {
    interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
        setFoo(foo: string | number | []): this;
        setBar(bar: string | number | []): this;
    }
}
```

One solution would be to eliminate the `CustomType` and explicitly type parameters with their multi-types, but this becomes rather inconvenient with an increasing number of methods that use the same type as it doesn't benefit from reusability plus it looks ugly to me.

### Imaginary Solution

```ts
export type CustomType = string | number | [];

declare global {
    interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
        setFoo(foo: inline CustomType): this; // <-- note the 'inline' here
        setBar(bar: inline CustomType): this;
    }
}
```

This would be ideal and in my imagination behave like the 'Ugly Solution', but unfortunately isn't supported. So what would be the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that the type `[]` is specifically a zero-length tuple, and not an arbitrary array like `any[]` or `Array<any>`.  Is that the type you really want?

Comment: `string | number | []` is simple enough that anything I can come up is, in my opinion, uglier.  Like, would [this](https://tsplay.dev/oN5x9w) be something you'd want to use?

Comment: Since I can't test it right now, out of curiosity, what happens if CustomType is not exported? Does that change anything?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the hint regarding `[]`. I meant to use `any[]`.
I'd consider your approach of declaring a `const` and then using `typeof` to get the type a little hacky, but given that this `CustomType` is used in quite a few places in that lib, I'm still willing to accept your code snippet as a valid answer for the sake of reusability and maintenance.

Comment: @IngoBürk Not exporting `CustomType` does not change anything in this regard. From my understanding, `export` just allows `import` to be used. And it seems to be good practice to `export` all your types and interfaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not currently possible.

There is an open GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#25784](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25784), asking for the ability to "drill down" into the IntelliSense quick info, which, if implemented, may or may not expand unions into their constituents.

There's also [microsoft/TypeScript#40780](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40780) which asks for an "alias" keyword that works similarly to what you're suggesting: basically a *type macro* that is eliminated by the time anyone consuming the code looks at it.  This issue was closed as a duplicate of a draft pull request for what looks like a slightly different feature.  So this line of research seemed to peter out fairly quickly.

---

So, workaround: create/declare a variable `x` of the type you'd like to inline away, and refer to this type as `typeof x`. At the call sites, IntelliSense should, I believe, resolve `typeof x` to the expanded type.  I can't guarantee that this will always happen (the details of how the compiler decides to render type information are a bit murky to me) but it seems to do this in my testing.  For example:

```
const __Custom: string | number | any[];

interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> {
  setFoo(foo: typeof __Custom): this;
  setBar(bar: typeof __Custom): this;
}
```

And then later:

```
declare const $: JQuery;
$.setBar(""); // IntelliSense says 
// setBar(bar: string | number | any[]): JQuery<HTMLElement>
```

This may or may not work for you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7xHAvHADAbgChCATYBAGwEMpg4BzCiAIyorgG9C5EV04A+gIDCAV3QQAtgC446KAEtk9OAB84yUZObAoauFWQBPANoBdIjyUxdAMyoI6AKQCKo3UYA8AFQCiFYElgZHgcAAlvAFkAGX9A4JgAPk5uHjlgGAAxCAgAClsc2RgjMGAIW0ERcRgpAEoigAsFVEs01AyAIRpc1igikrKKoTEJSXq4GCaW1IBfQjnScmpaXjR4ABJZV3coIyJ1gDp2mC6oXIAic9r8OAB6W7gASRDgCgoFAGVg9rkqI1Q4IR7ukTt1erJ5EoVOpNNpdPpDKYzONth5PBEYnEgiFEkA)